# Nodejs Express - can't find index.html

Tags: node.js, express

This is the structure of my code directory:

```
myCode
|-src
   |-Server.js
   |-public
      |-index.html
      |-myScript.js
```

I just run from myCode directory the `$node src/Server.js` and I want to see the `index.html/reco` file if I input the address `localhost` in my broswer.

Server.js just have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/reco', express.static(__dirname + '/src/public'));
app.listen(8080, function() { console.log('started');});
```

The Servers correctly starts but in the browser the following error is shown:

> Cannot GET /reco

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change the path in app.use.
Should be only `/public/` since it starts reading from the position of Server.js itself.